# Remove LF with preg_replace within CSV

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I try to delete some line feed within an CSV file with PHP preg_replace. 
I don't get it. I tried a lot. Maybe someone can help me with my code.

```
$content = "Halvah sweet ice.|Donut pastry candy canes bear claw toffee ice cream 
    cotton candy jelly-o. Pastry chocolate lemon drops biscuit muffin muffin apple pie croissant. Candy canes topping pudding biscuit. Cotton candy sweet mi bears chocolate. Croissant sesame snaps chocolate cake. Topping toffee oat cake cake. Biscuit| cheesecake powder";

$content = preg_replace('/^\|(.*)\n(.*)\|$/', "", $content);

// expected result
$content = "Halvah sweet ice.|Donut pastry candy canes bear claw toffee ice cream cotton candy jelly-o. Pastry chocolate lemon drops biscuit muffin muffin apple pie croissant. Candy canes topping pudding biscuit. Cotton candy sweet mi bears chocolate. Croissant sesame snaps chocolate cake. Topping toffee oat cake cake. Biscuit| cheesecake powder";
```

It should remove the line feed only between the | |, in example, the line feed after the word "cream".

Thanks!

Comment: If you paid attention to the warnings, you would see *preg_replace(): Unknown modifier '\' in /home/kVVtTY/prog.php on line 6*

Comment: Try [`$content = preg_replace_callback("/\|[^|]*\|/", function($m) {
 return str_replace(array("\n", "\r"), "", $m[0]);
} , $content);`](https://ideone.com/J0tdns).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew you're right, I used an old code version. I found the example /\\\\n/ at stack and I gave it a try to make sure the escaping of the \n is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `^\|(.*)\n(.*)\|$` pattern matches a `|` at the string start, then any 0+ chars other than line breaks, `\n`, again any 0+ chars other than line breaks and a `|` at the end of string. So, basically, you empty such strings with the code, not removing the newline symbol only.

You may match all `|...|` substrings and remove multiple line breaks inside them in one go using a simple `\|[^|]+\|` regex in a `preg_replace_callback` function:

```
$content = preg_replace_callback("/\|[^|]*\|/", function($m) {
    return str_replace(array("\n", "\r"), "", $m[0]);
} , $content);
echo str_replace("\n", "NEWLINE", $content); // => Note there is no  NEWLINE in the output
```

See the [PHP demo](https://ideone.com/J0tdns).